# Knapsack variation in Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve this exercise: we are given n items, where each has a given nonnegative weigth w1,w2,...,wn and value v1,v2,...,vn, and a knapsack with max weigth capacity W. I have to find a subset S of maximum value, subject to two restricions: 1) the total weight of the set should not exceed W; 2) I can't take objects with consecutive index.

For example, with n = 10, possible solutions are {1, 4, 6, 9}, {2, 4, 10} o {1, 10}.

How can I build a correct recurrence?

Comment: have you looked at any of the N similar questions already asked and answered? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Knapsack

Comment: Yes, but I didn't find a solution that solves this kind of variation

Comment: fair enough. Had to ask!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that the knapsack recursive formula used for the DP solution is:

```
D(i,w) = max { D(i-1,w) , D(i-1,w-weight[i]) + value[i] }
```

In your modified problem, if you chose to take `i` - you cannot take `i-1`, resulting in the modification of:

```
D(i,w) = max { D(i-1,w) , D(i-2,w-weight[i]) + value[i] }
                              ^
                          note here 
                       i-2 instead of i-1
```

Similar to classic knapsack, it is also an exhaustive search - and thus provides optimal solution for the same reasons.

The idea is given that you have decided to chose `i` - you cannot chose `i-1`, so find the optimal solution that uses at most the item `i-2`. (no change from the original if you decided to exclude `i`)

Comment: @user1966276: You are most welcome, I hope it helps you and that you understand *why* it works

Comment: And what's the recursive formula if I can take objects with consecutive index but, this time, I can take each object more than once (i.e. twice or more - bounded knapsack)?

Comment: `D(i,w) = max { D(i-1,w) , D(i,w-weight[i]) + value[i] }` - do not decrease `i` if you have chosen the item (it will be decreased when you later chose to stop taking it)